# Do I need to use following function for string escaping in PHP?

Tags: php, string, escaping

```
function escape($value){
    $magic_quotes_active = get_magic_quotes_gpc();
    $new_enough_php = function_exists("mysql_real_escape_string");
      if ($new_enough_php) {
        if ($magic_quotes_active) {
            $value = stripslashes($value);
            $value = mysql_real_escape_string($value);
        }
        elseif (!$magic_quotes_active) {
            $value = addslashes($value);
        }
        return $value;
    }
}
```

For a long time I have been using above function for escaping string ? Now, I want to ask that do I need to use that function (I found that over internet for escaping string that works with most versions of PHP) ? OR Its making things unnecesseraily complex ?

Comment: if you continue using mysql_* functions, then yes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you should, in fact, avoid using functions like these at all cost! What you should be looking into is the use of prepared statements. 
Check the [doc pages](http://www.php.net/mysql_connect) of any of the `mysql_*` functions, and notice the red warning-thing: the extension has begun the deprecation process, instead `PDO` or `mysqli_*` is suggested.

To avoid injection, prepared statements are what you should use... read a couple of articles on the matter, and look into the advantages of both `PDO` and `mysqli_*`. That's, I'm afraid the only way forward...

Comment: @YousufIqbal: I'm going to +1 you, just for being the first person on SO that listens to reason. Every day countless comments are being left here saying `mysql_*` is being deprecated. You're the first to accept that and switch to the more modern, safer, more powerful and overall better option without making a fuss. Thank you for restoring my faith in man kind! :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need such functions. Typically it's enough to use `addslashes(...)`. In special cases see the documentation, like @Elias Van Ootegem recommended

Comment: `addslashes()` should never be used when you need to escape a string to use in a database.