# combining strip_tags and mysql_real_escape_string in php when form submission

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does mysql_real_escape_string() FULLY protect against SQL injection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1220182/does-mysql-real-escape-string-fully-protect-against-sql-injection)

In my page I created a form and what I want to do is when posting the field value in php coding I want to use both the `strip_tags` and `mysql_real_escap_string` as :

```
$res = stript_tags(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name']));
```

Is the above coding correct for secure submission of input field names or it creates any problem when submission.

Comment: no problem will occur, you can use it....:)

Comment: You probably don't want to use `strip_tags()`, as for `mysql_real_escape_string()`, [**see here for more info**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1220182/does-mysql-real-escape-string-fully-protect-against-sql-injection)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In itself, this should work just fine. But personally, I'd advise you *not* to use `mysql_real_escape_string` at all. I believe I'm right in thinking you're using the `mysql_*` extension, which is being deprecated. Do yourself a favour and switch to either `PDO` or `mysqli_*`, preferably PDO.

These are more modern extensions, that support *prepared statments*
[see my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13108695/do-i-need-to-use-following-function-for-string-escaping-in-php/13108751#13108751) for a couple of links. Also, see [Bobby tables](http://www.bobby-tables.com) on why prepared statements are a far safer bet than manually escaping data.

As @phant0m says: use of `mysql_real_escape_string` isn't full-proof (see the link in his comment). There's also a couple of pitfalls when using functions like `strip_tags` and especially `stripslashes`: when you're processing data, it's not unimaginable that, at some point, the data contains something like `Foo\'s Bar`, and, as the docs say:

> If magic_quotes_sybase is on, no backslashes are stripped off but two apostrophes are replaced by one instead.

Try figuring out what the result of `stripslashes(mysql_real_escape_string($data));` will be...

When using `strip_tags`, it's important to note that the *allowable tags* will **keep their attributes**, which may contain slashes, colons, semicolons, dashes, quotes and various other chars you wouldn't want to see messing up your query...
For more possible issues with `strip_tags`, have a look [at this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/585358/security-of-strip-tags-and-mysqli-real-escape-string?rq=1)

Comment: I'l go for PDO. Any sites for the complete PDO reference for developers. Thanks a lot for the useful answer

Comment: You might want to add a statement concerning the OP's use of `strip_tags()` to fully answer the question.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly: the [mysql_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) function will ***help*** prevent SQL injections (to a degree), but it is not the **best** way to go about securing your database. There are known vulnerabilities with the function when different connection charsets are not used properly and more importantly, the mysql functions are **no longer recommended**. To quote PHP.net:

> Use of this extension is discouraged.

The best way to guard against SQL injections is to use [prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement). To use prepared statements, you should switch to the [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) object or [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php).

Secondly, you shouldn't really be using [strip_tags](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) on input. Why? Because if a user enters something inside tags, then you're going to experience a loss of [data integrity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_integrity). Personally, I think that strip_tags should only be used on output. i.e. when you're displaying user-entered data.

Thirdly, strip_tags won't guard against all XSS attacks. Personally, for guarding against XSS; I'd go for something like:

```
echo htmlspecialchars($stringToOutput, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
```

[htmlspecialchars](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) will convert all special characters to their relevant HTML entities.

Answer (score 1):

The code you posted will work. However, it is better to escape the string at the *latest moment possible*. This will keep your variables clean, since you don't want to work with escaped strings before the actual query.

An example:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE column1 = '". mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name']) ."'";
```

Also note that mysql_* functions are not maintained anymore - you could use [mysqli_*](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) instead, but the best way is to use prepared statements with [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Comment: `mysql_*` are not deprecated, just not maintained anymore - they'll be deprecated in the next major release (hopefully). Also: I'd suggest using PDO instead of `mysqli_*` simply because `mysqli_*` still allows for old-school procedural coding (which is what we're trying to get away from) and `PDO` offers an array of drivers, for DB's _other_ than MySQL... so it's more future-proof

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem Thanks for your input! I edited the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You should consider using some framework for that instead of doing it manually. Take a look at [Zend_Db](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.db.html) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)(read prepared statements).

An example with PDO:

```
$dsn = 'mysql:dbname=testdb;host=127.0.0.1';
$user = 'dbuser';
$password = 'dbpass';
try {
    $dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
$st = $dbh->prepare( '
    INSERT INTO fruits( name, colour )
    VALUES( :name, ":colour" )
';
$st->execute( array( ':name' => 'Apple', ':colour' => 'red' ) );
```